# Electronics noises

Tags: electronic-music, electronics

In order to perform music like Vangelis' *Memories of green*, I would like to generate or find a track with typical cliché electronics and retro-futuristic computer sounds from the first computers era, similar also to those in *Welcome to the machine*, by Pink Floyd, and other space-themed productions.

Is there any site where I could find, for example, some open sources to use in Reason or similar software, or just some audio files to use as background? Else, what could be a good starting point and recommendations to build my own track with these tools?

Answer (score 1):

Requests to find off-site resources, locating or naming a particular sound are often relevant only to the original asker & rarely useful to future readers. They are also an unsearchable resource.

If you want to tackle this from scratch yourself, then look into 'retro' synthesis plugins, VSTs etc. There are now so many of these that top searches in google will start with pages of 'which is best' comparison sites to get you started. A lot of them are freeware, so all you need is a VST-compatible DAW.
As most of these retro machines came originally with almost no instructions & certainly no presets, you could learn just like the original composers did… by pushing buttons & twiddling knobs until you find something you like.

Of course, as they're now all in VST format, in line with the modern desire for instant gratification, they will come with reams of presets & quite likely a decent manual too.